# How do I stop ssh-agent trying all keys with agent forwarding?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Often I'll connect via SSH to VM instances to deploy code from private Bitbucket repositories, cloning repositories via git over SSH.  Today I was getting the error:

`conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.`

A quick search showed it was the problem described in [Repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306435/repository-access-denied-access-via-a-deployment-key-is-read-only). The issue is my forwarded SSH agent was trying to connect to Bitbucket with a Vagrant development key that I'd added since I'd last tried to clone a private repository over SSH. (Removing the Vagrant key from my `.ssh` directory allowed me access to the private repositories again.)

My SSH `config` is:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and locally this seems to behave as expected. The output of `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` shows

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/bitbucket_key
```

whereas when I'm connected to another server over SSH:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: steve@not_a_bitbucket_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: steve@still_not_a_bitbucket_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: steve@bitbucket_key
```

Is there some other configuration other than `IdentitiesOnly` that I'm missing to ensure only the requested keys are sent to particular servers when using agent forwarding?

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenSSH 5.9p1 installed.

Comment: Do you know about `ssh-agent-proxy`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `ForwardAgent no` to your ssh config file for host bitbucket?

Helpful sources: 
https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/
https://support.ssh.com/manuals/server-zos-admin/55/Disabling_Agent_Forwarding.html

Edit: I reread your question's title (sorry I just woke up), but add `ForwardAgent no` to your config for all hosts if you don't want it to send to every machine you ssh to and just add `ForwardAgent yes` to hosts that you wish ssh agent forwarding to be active.